# NetworkX: How can I resolve raise NetworkXError( "Edge tuple %s must be a 2-tuple or 3-tuple." % (e,))

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to manually browse and pinpoint where in my edges is the cause of this error but I can't find it because of the size of the data.

Is there any way to programatically catch this? Why is this error also happening? This is coming from a shapefile, so will there really be a possibility that an element will not be a 2 or 3 tuple?

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx/classes/graph.py", line 865, in add_edges_from
"Edge tuple %s must be a 2-tuple or 3-tuple." % (e,))
NetworkXError: Edge tuple (437,) must be a 2-tuple or 3-tuple.
```

I manually convert geojson to ESRI shapefile using this code:

```
def geojson_to_shp(request,):
routes = Route.objects.filter(route_long__contains="Test")
routes_json = serialize('geojson', routes, fields=('route_type', 'route_long', 'route_id', 'wkb_geometry',))
routes_geojson = json.loads(routes_json)
routes_geojson.pop('crs', None)
#routes_geojson = json.dumps(routes_geojson)

schema = {'geometry': 'LineString', 'properties': {'route_id': 'str', 'route_type':'str', 'route_long':'str'}}

now = datetime.date.today()
outfilepath = 'files/{0}/{1}.shp'.format(str(now), str(now))
check_if_path_exists(outfilepath)
#this_file = Path(filepath)
#if this_file.is_file() and filepath.lower().endswith(('.geojson', '.json')):

with collection(outfilepath, "w", "ESRI Shapefile", schema) as outfile:
    routes = routes_geojson["features"]
#    rlinestring_shp = asShape(geom)
    for r in routes:
        rlinestring_shp = asShape(r['geometry'])
        outfile.write({
            'properties': r['properties'],
            'geometry': mapping(rlinestring_shp)
        })

render_network()

return render(request, 'plexus/network/shapefile.html', {'test':routes})

def render_network():
    directory  = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'files/2017-10-25/2017-10-25.shp')
#G = ox.graph_from_polygon(directory, network_type="drive")
net = nx.DiGraph()
shp = ogr.Open(directory)
for lyr in shp:
    fields = [x.GetName() for x in lyr.schema]



#G = nx.read_shp(directory, simplify=False)

#print("NODES: " + str(len(G.nodes())))
#print("EDGES: " + str(len(G.edges())))
#print(nx.is_directed(G))

def check_if_path_exists(filepath):
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(filepath)):
        try:
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filepath))
        except OSError as exc:
            if exc.errno != os.errno.EEXIST:
```

Additionally, I load the shapefile in mapshaper.org to validate it, and it draws the shape without any errors.

Comment: Could you give some more specifics? By "shapefile" do you mean an ArcGIS shapefile? How are you passing it to NetworkX?

Comment: @senderle oh sorry edited

Comment: @senderle it's ok I don't mind at all. Where can I upload it temporarily? Sorry I'm a newbie. I just started asking more in SO recently so I'm not familiar with temporary tools